# What common ways are there to release persistent memory usage not released by ARC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, persistent

As I move from one viewcontroller to another (containing images, a scrollview, labels and other stuf) my persistent is not released.

In instruments it currently looks like this:

[image]

**Facts:**

- I'm using Objective-C, ARC and Auto Layout
- My "- (void)dealloc{ }" is being called but there is nothing in it
- NSZombie is not enabled

**I have tried:**

1. Replacing all occurrences of self with weakSelf

   ```
   typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
   ```
2. I use imageWithContentsOfFile not imageNamed

   ```
   [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thumbUp" ofType:@"png"]]

   not

   [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbUp.png"]
   ```

**In "-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated" I have:**

3. Invalidate all timers

   ```
   [_searchAnimationTimer invalidate];
   ```
4. Setting all stuff to nil (every object and variable)

   ```
   _searchAnimationTimer = nil;
   ```
5. Removing observers

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:weakSelf]
   ```
6. Setting all delegates to nil

   ```
   [self.tableView setDelegate:nil];
   ```
7. Setting all data sources to nil

   ```
   [self.tableView setDataSource:nil];
   ```
8. I've added *[super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];* in the end of *"-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated"*

   ```
   -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
      //Code here
      [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
   }
   ```

**In "- (void)viewDidLoad" I:**

9. Dismiss ViewControllers using both

   ```
   [weakSelf.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
10. and

    ```
    _mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    _vc = [_mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Omraden"];
    [_vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{ }];
    ```

**In .h I have:**

11. I have created an IBOutlet for all objects in storyboard.
12. And set all @property to weak

    ```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
    ```

Whats my next step? What common changes can I do? I'm new at memory management. Need more info? I'll answer fast :)

#### List of solutions so far:

- In "-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated", also set the image of every UIimageView to nil like this:

  ```
  _someImageView.image = nil;
  ```
- I also added this:

  ```
  for (CALayer* layer in [weakSelf.view.layer sublayers])
  {
     [layer removeAllAnimations];
  }
  ```
- Started using @autoreleasepool inside for-statements (not sure where else to use it)

  ```
  @autoreleasepool{ 
     //code 
  }
  ```

Comment: It seems to be saying that image data is the biggest contributor to memory use by far.  Perhaps there are things you can do to reduce image sizes or remove them from memory when not needed, but other reductions won't have much impact on the total used.

Comment: I don't think the second viewController is releasing the images from the first viewController (4 jpg and 1 png images), any common solutions to try?

Comment: How do I remove them from memory when not needed? Set _exampleImage to nil? Is it bad to make every imageView a @property?

Comment: Should "I remove them from memory when not needed" as soon as I can or just in the viewDidDisappear? - I think this is a key question :)